# Customizing chapter's titles in the Bringhurst style

Tags: classicthesis

I use `classic thesis` and I wondered if someone tried to customize the title of the chapters in the way Robert Bringhurst did in his *The Elements of typographic style* ? If it was the case, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have an image of such a chapter page?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage{classicthesis} %


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\relax}
        {\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}%
        \color{halfgray}\scalebox{1.5}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
        {0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The grand design}
\section{First principles}
\subsection{Typography exists to honour content}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, like this one and it works well. Many thanks. But, finally, I am wondering if the result is what I am searching for... In fact, I am trying a lot of commands and I am about to change nothing at all at classic thesis in the end...

Comment: I would like to reduce a little bit the size of the chapter number. How can I do that ?

Comment: @domi Change `1.5` in `\scalebox{1.5}{...`