# Apply Bringhurst style to standard book class

Tags: titlesec

How can [the following](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201065/48787) (`titleformat` part) be applied to standard book class and without `classicthesis`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage{classicthesis} %


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\relax}
        {\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}%
        \color{halfgray}\scalebox{1.5}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
        {0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The grand design}
\section{First principles}
\subsection{Typography exists to honour content}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

For example, why does the following give `Undefined control sequence. [\chapter{The grand design}]` error:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}    

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\relax}
        {\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}%
        \color{gray}\scalebox{1.5}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
        {0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}    

\begin{document}
\chapter{The grand design}
\section{First principles}
\subsection{Typography exists to honour content}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you don't want to use scrbook but book? Or what is your aim?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the standard, plain book class.

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex`, or `xelatex`, or `lualatex`? I ask because `classicthesis` has different definitions of some of those macros depending on the engine used.

Comment: @Torbjørn `pdflatex`

Comment: I had the wrong colour by the way, try `\colorlet{halfgray}{black!45}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works at least, I haven't done much comparison with the original.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
%\usepackage{classicthesis} %
\usepackage{titlesec} % for \titleformat
\usepackage{microtype} % for \textls, used in \spacedallcaps
\usepackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase, used in \spacedallcaps
\usepackage{xcolor} % for color

\colorlet{halfgray}{black!45} % color of chapter number

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapterNumber}{T1}{pplj}{m}{n}{70} % font definition
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\textls[160]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}} % used in chapter style

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\relax}
        {\mbox{}\marginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}% changed \oldmarginpar to \marginpar
        \color{halfgray}\scalebox{1.5}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
        {0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The grand design}
\section{First principles}
\subsection{Typography exists to honour content}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Regarding your last example, the complete error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mbox {}\oldmarginpar 
                                 {\vspace *{4\baselineskip }\color {gray}\sc...
l.23 \chapter{The grand design}

?
```

which means that `\oldmarginpar` is not defined (the last macro before the line break in the error). `classicthesis` does `\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar`, and then redefines `\marginpar`. So use `\marginpar` instead of `\oldmarginpar` in the `\titleformat`.

You will get errors for `\chapterNumber` and `\spacedallcaps` as well, as these are macros defined in `classicthesis.sty`. I got the definitions from there. Finally `halfgray` is a colour defined by `classicthesis`, so you need a definition of that as well.

Comment: How can I control horizontal location of the sectioning label (chapter number)? Here it is far right. Suppose I want nudge it a bit to the left.

Comment: @blackened `\hspace{-5pt}` just before `\color{halfgray}`?